# Tegram bot API token format

Tags: api, token, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to figure out the format of telegram bot tokens to implement some validity checks, but there seems not official format description.

from my token and what I have found on the net, I can assume the following:

- (up to) 46 characters length
- starts with (up to) 10 digits followed by :
- the remaining 35 characters are of class [[:alnum:]] plus - and _

can anyone (dis) confirm or point to documentation?

Comment: The first part (the internal user ID of the bot) can be up to 10 digits, not 9. User IDs are somewhat sequential, so newer bots (and normal users too) are more likely to have 10-digit IDs

Comment: I think this has changed over time. My bot code starts with 10 digits, a `:` and 35 'azAZ09', **46** total

Comment: You've made me curious, I've checked my last 14 tokens (as far as my history with the botFather goes), 2 start with **10** digits, the rest with **9**.  For special chars, I only had these: `__`, `-`, `_`

Comment: @0stone0, thanks this fits to my research, was the __ character really in one of your tokens or was it 2 _?

Comment: Yea, only the first part that could(?) contain 10 digits ;). It was part of the token, your right, 2x `_`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me summarize what we know so far:

- to verify that a telegram API token has the correct format AND is currently valid you must make a Telegram `getMe` API call, e.g. on command line:
  `curl -s https://api.telegram.org/botYOURTOKEN/getMe`

Nevertheless, we have some good guesses what a correct token must look like:

- it consists of 8-10 digits followed by a `:`
- the `:` is followed by a 35 character Telegram internal identifier/hash
- the identifier is consisting of character class `[[:alnum:]]` plus `_-`, this fit's the characters documented for the [deep linking parameter](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking)

Summary:

- Token format: `8-10 digits:35 alnum characters plus _-` , e.g. `123456789:AaZz0...AaZz9`
- Regex for testing: `/^[0-9]{8,10}:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{35}$/`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check validity of a bot's token you can use the `getMe` method.

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getme

> A simple method for testing your bot's auth token. Requires no
>   parameters. Returns basic information about the bot in form of a User
>   object.

Any non valid token will return 401 error.

I believe this would be a more robust approach than checking for correct formats.

Answer (score 0):

The `BOT token` consists of two parts. In `BOT_ID:BOT_ALPHANUMERIC_PART`  the `BOT_ID` is 8 to 10 digit long and the `BOT_ALPHANUMERIC_PART` has a length of 35 characters. So the total length is 43 to 45 characters.

If you want to validate a bot token then you can use: `https://api.telegram.org/bot< YOUR_BOT_TOKEN>/getMe`.
It will return the JSON data for your bot. It will throw a 401 error if the bot token is not valid.